# Поддерживает ли браузер пользователя определенный символ

Tags: javascript

Можно ли из приложения определить, поддерживает ли браузер пользователя какой-либо символ по его коду (unicode) или, например, поддерживает ли кириллицу? И вообще, я не совсем разобрался со шрифтами. От чего это зависит? От установленных в системе шрифтов, наверное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь о кириллице, то браузер — поддерживает. Но шрифтов, чтобы отобразить может не быть.

Проверить можно, наверное, разве что порисовав текст на canvas'е и сравнив нарисованное с требуемой литерой (что нетривиально), но это требует браузера, умеющего `<canvas>`, т.е. HTML5. Не верю, честно говоря, что современные браузеры идут в комплекте ОС, которые не тащат с собой кириллические шрифты. Если бы речь шла про CJK — другое дело, но европейские языки, как правило, умеют сейчас все.

Как решение, если проблемных клиентов слишком много — притащите через CSS'овский `@font-face` шрифт. Там символы точно будут.

Comment: Эти символы и так будут выводиться в `canvas`. Браузеры, не поддерживающие HTML5, не рассматриваются изначально. Символы: один из ниx кириллический, другой - "Ć". Необxодимо, чтобы символы верно отобразились и если это невозможно, не выводить иx, а сделать другое действие. У меня локально всё работает, но я не уверен, что у пользователей, не использующиx кириллицу, все заработает. Например, у меня некоторые символы из другиx языков не отображаются, вместо ниx квадратики.

Comment: все будет работать, все бравзери поддерживают кириллицу

Comment: Со шрифтами тоже иногда [проблемы бывают](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/582261/178988).