# Как узнать, поддерживает ли шрифт определенный символ?

Tags: php, шрифты

Приветствую. Каким образом можно узнать, что шрифт поддерживает определенный символ? То есть входные данные - файл шрифта и символ, выходные - true/false (поддерживает или нет). Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении искать. Желательно решение без библиотек. Язык - php.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Поддерживает ли браузер пользователя определенный символ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/38862/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb)

Comment: @Dantessss как связаны поддержка символа браузером и поддержка символа шрифтом?

Comment: Использовать модуль GD и попробовать отрисовать этот символ в картинку.

Comment: Не нужно ничего "куралесить". Шрифты обычные упакованные данные. Вот только понять их и распарсить вопрос еще тот :) В ответе одну библиотеку скинул, но с ней нужно еще разбираться.

Comment: Ну тут либо библиотека, либо самому нужно писать, что в итоге к одному и придет.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov а смысл? Вообще вопрос и возник от того, что при использовании php ImageMagick я отрисовываю текст, но некоторые символы не поддерживаются шрифтом и нужно мастерить механизм, который будет исправлять эту проблему (искать шрифт, который поддерживает этот символ и отрисовывать им).

Comment: @Nik, понял. Но это все равно кривое решение. Нужно заранее брать или руками формировать шрифт, в котором есть все необходимые символы. А предварительная подготовка такого шрифта должна производиться уж никак не средствами PHP.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov несомненно, это наилучший вариант. Но проблема заключается в том, что мне заранее неизвестен текст, который нужно будет отрисовывать. Он формируется динамически и может содержать любые символы. А я пока что не видел такого шрифта, у которого есть поддержка всех языков.

Answer (score 0):

Есть библиотека https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib, но документации к ней не нашел.

Придётся исходники «ковырять».

Или вот https://github.com/Pomax/PHP-Font-Parser/blob/master/fonttest.php

Вам вообще для какого типа шрифта надо?

---

https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib/issues/30

Comment: Ну, для TrueType. И не думал, что для простой задачи нужно выдумывать такие навороты...